# saving all variable values in matlab's workspace together with their names

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, save

I'd like to <s>save</s> print all my variables in my workspace to a file together with their names in a certain way:

```
%<*firstVariableName>firstVariableValue(s)%</firstVariableName>
%<*secondVariableName>secondVariableValue(s)%</secondVariableName>
```

I'd like to save each variable on a new line. I've experimented with the function who, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I also have problem getting it to save as UTF-8, is there a simple encoding setting that could be changed?

Comment: What about multidimensional variables? A 2D or a 3D matrix perhaps?

Comment: @RoneyMichael They could be ignored. I'm just going to use scalars, so   matrices could be excluded or be formatted weirdly.

Comment: So what about 1D vectors?

Comment: @RoneyMichael I'm only going to use scalars, but 1D vectors can be represented as 'element1 element2 element3 ...'

Answer (score 1):

The `who` function will save the names of the variables, but not the data in the variables.  If you'd like to save the actual variables, you should use the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function, and save it to a *.mat file.

If you're trying to get a list of the names of the variables formatted in a certain way, I'd recommend doing this:

```
varlist = who(variables);
```

`varlist` is a cell array.  You can then `fopen` to start writing to a file, iterate through the cell array using [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html), and `fclose` it when you're done. By the way, when you iterate, you should use `varlist{x}`, which will return the string (whereas `varlist(x)` will return the cell).

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not work in all cases, but it works well for numeric inputs. It may be modified appropriately as per your use case:

```
%Clears current workspace.
clear;

%Sample data.
a = 1;
b = [2 3];
new_var = [4;5];

%Relevant code.
my_var_list = who;
fid = fopen('my_var_list.txt','w');
for my_var_ii=1:numel(my_var_list)
    my_temp_var = eval(my_var_list{my_var_ii});
    my_temp_str = cellstr(strcat(sprintf('%%<*%s>', my_var_list{my_var_ii}), num2str(my_temp_var(:)'), sprintf('%%</%s>', my_var_list{my_var_ii})));
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', my_temp_str{:});
end
fclose(fid);
clear fid;
clear my_temp_var;
clear my_var_ii;
clear my_var_list;
clear my_temp_str;
```

Now my 'my_var_list.txt' will contain:

```
%<*a>1%</a>
%<*b>2  3%</b>
%<*new_var>4  5%</new_var>
```

Comment: Very nice!. To make it more robust and ignore the 'junk' I would recommend adding a simple check to see if something is a scalar, and otherwise go for the next variable.